# Setting up MongoDB + Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am new to Mongo DB and Django. I've been trying to use Mongo DB as my primary Database for Django. I've installed MongoDB and Django-nonrel as per the following link:

[Django - MongoDB setup](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/setup.html#django-mongodb-engine)

The version of django-nonrel, i am using is 1.7. Clone link to it:

`pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.7`

After following all steps, my settings.py in the django project file looks something like this:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
        'NAME': 'blink',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': 1234,
    }
}

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'djangotoolbox',
)
```

But while running the manage.py using the following command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I am getting an error like this,

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x104a95f80>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/sunilkumar/blink/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 222, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/sunilkumar/blink/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
        self.check_migrations()
      File "/Users/sunilkumar/blink/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 159, in check_migrations
        executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
      File "/Users/sunilkumar/blink/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 242, in __getitem__
        backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
      File "/Users/sunilkumar/blink/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 108, in load_backend
        return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
      File "/Users/sunilkumar/blink/lib/python3.3/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1584, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 584, in _check_name_wrapper
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1022, in load_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1003, in load_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_for_loader_wrapper
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 853, in _load_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 980, in get_code
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/Users/sunilkumar/blink/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django_mongodb_engine/base.py", line 265
        raise ImproperlyConfigured, exc_info[1], exc_info[2]
                                  ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am not able to understand what the error is. Can somebody please help.?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are using Python 3. But `django-mongodb-engine`, on which `django-nonrel` depends, doesn't even support Python 3 yet.

The syntax error above is actually valid in py3, but not in py2. Thus the error.

Perhaps you should consider using py2 for this project.

Comment: what about mongo engine? Does that support py3?

Comment: This mongo engine(the one you used above) depends on Django-nonrel. So I don't think it supports py3, either.

Answer (score 0):

In 2021 MongoDB supports Py3 and Django with 3 Engines. Its PyMongo, MongoEngine and Djongo.

- **PyMongo** is the standard driver through which MongoDB can interact with Django.
- **MongoEngine** is similar to a Object-Relational-Mapper in relational databases
- **djongo** transpiles all the SQL queries to MongoDB syntax queries.

[MongoDB Connection Examples](https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/mongodb-and-django)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).