# Error while setting up MongoDB with django using django mongodb engine on windows

Tags: python, django, mongodb

Steps I followed :

1. 'pip install git+htp://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.5'

It did not work, so I downloaded the zip from the site "htp://github.com/django-nonrel/django" and pasted the unzipped folder inside "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\temp\pip-m0d0y9bv-build".

2. 'pip install git+htp://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox'
3. 'pip install git+htp://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine'

NOTE

*** I have used 'htp' instead of 'https' as I have reputation less than 10.

4. configured my settings.py file as follows:-

.

```
import os       

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))         

SECRET_KEY = '4j*aieq$cn&sewl0s2#&m00+^oe%qg9p=@mlva96_r48nv-pkl'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
    'djangotoolbox',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'



DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 27017,


    }
}

SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'mongoengine.django.sessions.BSONSerializer'


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

5. I got the below error when i started running server using command 'python manage.py runserver'

.

```
c:\Python34\myproject>python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in pop
ulate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in impor
t_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 41, i
n <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 139, in __
new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 324, in ad
d_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 250, in
 contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length(
))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 36, in __geta
ttr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 240, in __getite
m__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_bac
kend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1467, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1572, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django_mongodb_engine\base.py", line 272
    raise ImproperlyConfigured, exc_info[1], exc_info[2]
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I missing here ? I have followed the steps from django - mongoengine documentation. However, I am unable to figure out the issue. Please help me out of this.

Answer (score 0):

Django-mongodb-engine does not appear to be compatible with Python 3. In any case, django-nonrel itself is based on Django 1.5, which is definitely not Python 3 compatible.

Comment: So, what can be a solution to this ? What version of django or python do I need to use ?