# Project Setup with Django 1.10, mongodb and Python 3.4.3

Tags: django, mongodb, python-3.4

Initially I have built projects with Django 1.5, django-mongoengine, python 2.7.8. I have started a project with an idea came up to my mind. I want to make it using latest versions of technologies therefore I stick with:

```
Django 1.10,
python 3.4.3
```

I want to use mongodb as my database. To run my project I am facing an error when I tried to connect mongodb with Django. Code in the settings.py is given as follow to connect database (The only change I made yet in file):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT':'27017',
        'NAME': 'Demo',
   }
}
```

Please help me out to setup project so that I can proceed with my work. Also the environment I have setup for my project is:

```
Django  1.10.1
django-mongodb-engine   0.6.0   
django-mongodb-engine-py3   0.6.0.1 
django-nonrel-enuff 0.4 
django-toolbox  0.1 
djangotoolbox   1.8.0
mongoengine 0.10.6
pip 8.1.2
pymongo 3.3.0
setuptools  27.2.0
```

Error that I am facing is:

```
File "/home/username/Documents/Projects /ProjectsENV/lib/python3.4/site-  packages/django_mongodb_engine/base.py", line 272
   raise ImproperlyConfigured, exc_info[1], exc_info[2]
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on the above answer. **You *can* actually use Django with MongoDB directly.**

It is possible to use django AS IS with MongoDB as your backend [djongo](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo)

It is a compiler that converts SQL queries into mongodb syntax. Using this all Django features work as is.

Disclosure: I have contributed to this project and all Django contrib models work fine with this as the backend connector.

Comment: djongo has serious issues. It works fine first but then raises many different errors

Answer (score 3):

**You can't use the *normal Django* with  django-mongodb-engine**.

django-mongodb-engine requires the [Django-nonrel](https://github.com/django-nonrel) package to be installed, instead of the normal Django, which is several minor versions behind the current release of the official Django (*1.10*).

If you want to use the official django with MongoDB and be provided with an ORM like layer, your best bet is probably [Mongoengine](http://mongoengine.org/) which works with the official version of Django.

Comment: This is not working for django > 2.0. Is there a way to get the mongodb connection for django 2.0 or more.

Comment: "'django_mongodb_engine' isn't an available database backend" This is the error I'm getting for django 2.0 and more