# How to integrate MongoDB in Django1.10 and Python3.5?

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, mongoengine, django-mongodb-engine

I would like to use mongoDB as a database on behalf SQL for my django project. Where in we are developing the apps with django1.10 and python-3.5 version. We installed MongoDB in ubuntu-16.02LTE and thought to use MongoEngine to work with python3.5 and Django-1.10. But we don't have proper document to integrate this in python and Django. 
1) Did python 3.5 or django-1.10 support this procedure? if Yes please share document to refer
You answer to solve this more valuable for us

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555701/project-setup-with-django-1-10-mongodb-and-python-3-4-3) help? It looks like MongoDB doesn't work with Django, and you will have to use [mongoengine](http://mongoengine.org/).

Comment: Mongo Engine is not stable with django1.9.

Comment: Have you tried other Django - MonogoDB connectors like [djongo](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/). It works fine with in my experience.